# How can one hightlight a word after a specific token?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make a VSC extension to hightlight a custom language and I face a problem: I need to hightlight a variable identifier in a specific way only if it's right after an opening paren (it's a lisp like).

So far, I've tried multiple variations of this (in my .tmLanguage.json, under the repository field):

```json
        "builtins": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "begin": "\\(([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_\\?:']*)",
                    "beginCaptures": {
                        "1": { "name": "entity.name.function.arkscript" }
                    },
                    "name": "entity.name.function.afterparen.arkscript"
                },
                {
                    "name": "keyword.operator.ark",
                    "match": "(\\+|\\-|\\*|/|<|>|<=|>=|!=|=|@)"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I know for sure that in the beginCaptures, the "0" is refering to everything, thus "1" must be the thing I matched, but using the scope inspector, I can see it's doesn't work for `(hello "test")`. The string is colored correctly but hello has the scope of a variable, not of a builtin.

If anyone knows a way around please let me know

Comment: consider this for the operators `"(<=|>=|!=|[-+*/<>=@])"` first the multi char operators because `<` and `>` are prefixes of these, no need to escape if inside a char class

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that